# Split records in chunks with upper and lower limit?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table (`Db2`) with a few million records. A lot of records have been deleted from the table in the past, therefore ROW_NUMBER != PRIMARY KEY. For e.g. If primary key generation starts from 1, then a record with id 1000 may be the 756th record if ordered by primary key.

I have a requirement to show the data in the following way. For e.g.

```
Chunk   LowerLimitId   UpperLimitId

Chunk1  1               1098       // n = 1000 records between 1 and 1098

Chunk2  1099            2225       // n = 1000 records between 1099 and 2225

Chunk3  2226            3352       // n = 1000 records between 2226 and 3352
```

---

and so on....

Basically the total records between LowerLimit and Upper Limit always have to be 1000.

i.e.

```
"select count(*) from Table where id between 1 and 1098" = 1000

"select count(*) from Table where id between 1099 and 2225" = 1000

"select count(*) from Table where id between 2226 and 3352" = 1000 and so on
```

Is there any db2 clause or function do achieve this? I'm not asking for a full query. Just a direction to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate row number with help of [analytic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html) function `row_number`and split data by it into chuncks.

Example query

> ```
> with t(id) as (
>   select *
>   from ( values (1), (3), (5), (6), (20), (13), (25), (23) )
> )
> , a as (
>   select
>     t.id
>     , trunc((row_number() over(order by id asc) - 1) / 3) as grp
>   from t
> )
> select
>   concat('Chunk', grp + 1) as chunk
>   , min(id) as LowerLimitId
>   , max(id) as UpperLimitId
> from a
> group by grp
> ```
>
> ```
>  CHUNK | LOWERLIMITID | UPPERLIMITID
> -----: | -----------: | -----------:
> Chunk1 |            1 |            5
> Chunk2 |            6 |           20
> Chunk3 |           23 |           25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=095c010e61b662f465d7811c375880a5)*

Comment: You should actually show the query that answers the question.  Correct answer, but it leaves a bit to be inferred.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for noticing. Updated the answer to return results in requested format

Answer (score 0):

@astentx's answer is already good. I have just improved it to adapt to the actual requirement.

```
with t(id) as (
  select *
  from ( values (1), (3), (5), (6), (20), (13), (25), (23) )
)
, a as (
  select 
    t.id,
    trunc((row_number() over(order by id asc) - 1) / 3) as grp
  from t
)
select
    a.grp,
    MIN(a.id) as startId,
    MAX(a.id) as endId
from a
group by a.grp
```

[Sql Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=7536c67535158d770184b7c65d604a4b)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows functions to do this. Get the row_number for each row and then you will be able to select chunks. selection can be done dynamically or statically.

Row_Number() over order by primaryKeyColumn  ....

If you can post the table script with data, I can post a complete answer for this.
@bluelurker